# string manipulations in php

Tags: php, regex

I have a function:

```
function Validate($name)
{
    $rename = 'Rename' .$name;
    if (strlen($rename) > 50) {
        $rename = substr($rename, 0, 48) . '..';
    }
    return $rename;
}
```

The function is called as follows:

```
$data['name'] = Validate($duplicate->name."_").$i++;
```

If name is 50 characters then it is cut-shortened to 48 characters and extra .. at the end . In case if the name is 50characters ending with .._somedigits.
I would like to do $rename = substr($rename, 0, 45) . '..'.$suffix; I would like to have this extra check with sffix
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: just concat $suffix at the end ?

`$rename = substr($rename, 0, 48) . '..' . $suffix;`

Comment: When `$suffix` been appended?

Comment: So your `Validate` function manipulates the string? That's logical ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are concatenating `$rename = 'Rename' .$name;` and then you get the [strlen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) based on that `$rename`. So that adds "Rename" to the length of the string.

If that is you intention, you could use a regex [`_\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/ZHiFlI/1) to check if the string ends with and underscore and one or more digits.

```
function Validate($name)
{
    $suffix = "suffix";
    $rename = 'Rename' . $name;
    $re = '/_\d+$/';
    if (strlen($rename) > 50) {
        if (preg_match($re, $rename)) {
            return substr($rename, 0, 45) . '..' . $suffix;
        }
        return substr($rename, 0, 48) . '..';

    }
    return $rename;
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/UUI4c)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex `^.*_0$`

If this regex matches then you can make substring to 45 characters.
[Reg](https://regex101.com/r/rfrUrg/5)

Answer (score 0):

```
$strings = [
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_12',
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx',
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_12',
];
foreach($strings as $str) {
    if (preg_match('/_\d+$/', $str)) {
        echo preg_replace('/^(?=.{51}).{45}\K.+(_\d+)$/', '..$1', $str),"\n";
    } else {
        echo preg_replace('/^(?=.{51}).{48}\K.+$/', '..', $str),"\n";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_12
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuv..
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrs.._12
```

**First regex explain:**

```
^               : beginning of string
    (?=.{51})   : lookahead, 0-length assertion that makes sure we have, at least, 51 characters
    .{45}       : exactly 45 characters
    \K          : forget all we have seen until this position
    .+          : 1 or more any character
    (_\d+)      : group 1, underscore and last digits
$               : end of line
```

**Second regex explain:**

```
^               : beginning of string
    (?=.{51})   : lookahead, 0-length assertion that makes sure we have, at least, 51 characters
    .{48}       : exactly 48 characters
    \K          : forget all we have seen until this position
    .+          : 1 or more any character
$               : end of line
```